# I would like to plot a specific (given x,y) line on a ggplot that I have already construct [R]

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")

strike<-c(44,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,
      57,58,60,64,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,
      54,56,58,35,40,44,45,46,48,50,51,52,
      53,54,55,56,58,60,70,80,35,40,45,46,
      48,50,52,54,56,58,60,70,40,45,50,52,
      54,60,70)



optionprice <- c(7.25,7.25,5.1,5.2,4.47,3.45,1.95,2,1.3,
             0.8,0.44,0.28,0.14,0.26,0.08,0.25,5.48,
             4.35,5.5,4.82,3.25,2.67,2.55,1.9,1.4,
             0.85,0.4,18.16,11.31,9.5,7.35,7.05,5.25,
             4.2,2.44,2.9,1.6,1.9,1.4,1.15,0.65,0.4,
             0.08,0.06,15.7,12.25,8.5,7.6,6.6,5.15,3.9,
             2.85,1.95,1.45,1.1,0.22,12.65,8.5,
             5.07,4.3,3.55,1.63,0.44)

  Expiration <- c('2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20',
                    '2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20',
                    '2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20',
                    '2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20','2017-10-20',
                    '2017-11-17','2017-11-17','2017-11-17','2017-11-17',
                    '2017-11-17','2017-11-17','2017-11-17','2017-11-17',
                    '2017-11-17','2017-11-17','2017-11-17',
                    '2017-12-15','2017-12-15','2017-12-15',
                    '2017-12-15','2017-12-15','2017-12-15',
                    '2017-12-15','2017-12-15','2017-12-15',
                    '2017-12-15','2017-12-15','2017-12-15',
                    '2017-12-15','2017-12-15','2017-12-15',
                    '2017-12-15','2017-12-15',
                    '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', 
                    '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16', '2018-03-16',
                    '2018-06-15', '2018-06-15', '2018-06-15', '2018-06-15', '2018-06-15', '2018-06-15',
                    '2018-06-15')


Philips <- data.frame(strike, optionprice, as.factor(Expiration))


IrisPlot.shape <- ggplot(Philips, aes(strike, optionprice, shape = 
Expiration, colour = Expiration))+ geom_point(size = 4)+labs(x = 
"Strike/Exercise price")+labs(y = "Option Price")



print(IrisPlot.shape +  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 
17,18,19)) + scale_colour_manual(values = c("chartreuse4", 
"chocolate", "slateblue4","black","purple")))
```

and I would like to add in this plot a specific line which has x,y values respectively:

```
striking=seq(10, 53.49, length.out=63)
calling=53.49-striking
```

I would like this line to be included in the first plot and also a legend which it will say: Payoff . I attach a picture of this plot to see what I have already done. Thanks in advance.

[this is the figure I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UN7v.png)

Comment: @Axeman I just provided the data. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `geom_line` and turn of inheritance of aesthetics:

```
ggplot(Philips, aes(strike, optionprice, shape = Expiration, colour = Expiration)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = striking, y = calling, lty = 'payoff'), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.4) + 
  labs(x = "Strike/Exercise price", y = "Option Price") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 17,18,19)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("chartreuse4", "chocolate", "slateblue4","black","purple"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use theme line argument please refer below code. Hope this works fine.

IrisPlot.shape <- ggplot(Philips, aes(strike, optionprice, shape = Expiration, colour = Expiration)) + geom_point(size = 4) +labs(x = "Strike/Exercise price")+labs(y = "Option Price") + theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 2),axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 2))